# How to remote debug STM32 code with gdb using stlink-tools on linux?

Tags: arm, stm32, cross-compiling

On linux, using `stlink-tools`, I have a STM32 board that runs code which must be debugged. How to proceed?

The code is built on host (x86 PC) with debug flag using `gcc-arm-none-eabi` for STM32 target (arm):

```
>> sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi
>> make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc  ... -g -O0 ... -o blink01.c.o -c blink01.c
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc ... -g -O0 blink01.c.o -o blink01.elf
```

Then stripped to reduce the size of the binary:

```
>> /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary blink01.elf blink01.bin
```

Then the reduced binary is flashed to the STM32 board using STM tools:

```
>> sudo apt install stlink-tools
>> st-flash write blink01.bin 0x08000000
...
INFO common.c: Flash written and verified! jolly good!
```

Then running in one terminal gdbserver:

```
>> st-util
st-util
INFO common.c: F303 high density: 64 KiB SRAM, 512 KiB flash in at least 2 KiB pages.
INFO gdb-server.c: Listening at *:4242...
```

And in another terminal, running (note using .elf on host with debug symbols and .bin on target without symbol as it's supposes to work this way according to a doc I read somewhere):

```
>> sudo apt-get install gdb-arm-none-eabi
>> gdb-multiarch
(gdb) set remote exec-file /blink01.bin
(gdb) file blink01.elf
Reading symbols from blink01.elf...
(gdb) target extended-remote localhost:4242
Remote debugging using localhost:4242
0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Symbols seems to screwed `0x00000000 in ??`: no stack available and breakpoint can be set but are never hit when running `gdb`. Seems symbols can not be used: how to fix this?

**EDIT**

On host:

```
>> uname -a
Linux yoda 6.5.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.5.10-1 (2023-11-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
>> arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:12.2.rel1-1) 12.2.1 20221205
>> gdb-multiarch --version
GNU gdb (Debian 13.2-1) 13.2
```

**EDIT**

Disabling watch dogs I indeed get gdb work better (symbol and stack OK)

```
>> git diff
diff --git a/src/blink01.c b/src/blink01.c
index 1fba10e..86f23f5 100644
--- a/src/blink01.c
+++ b/src/blink01.c
@@ -169,6 +169,17 @@ void main(void) {
   GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_5; /* BR: Bit Reset. */
+
+#ifdef DEBUG
+  #define DBGMCU_APB1_FZ ( * ( ( volatile unsigned long * ) 0xE0042008 ) )
+  DBGMCU_APB1_FZ |= DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_IWDG_STOP;
+  DBGMCU_APB1_FZ |= DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_WWDG_STOP;
+#endif
 #endif
```

But gdb doesn't stop on breakpoint and I can't list. Any clue why?

```
(gdb) file blink01.elf
Reading symbols from blink01.elf...
(gdb) b vBlink
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8002f4c
(gdb) target extended-remote localhost:4242
Remote debugging using localhost:4242
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.
0x08002750 in xPortStartScheduler ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x08002750 in xPortStartScheduler ()
#1  0x08000b9c in vTaskStartScheduler ()
#2  0x08003042 in main ()
(gdb) l
1   ../../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/machine/arm/memcpy-armv7m.S: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Why not openocd / gdb

Comment: Don't use the command 'set remote exec-file'.  You only need to specify 'file' and 'target'.  The other issue is that you might need to enable 'debug' on the STM32.  It is possible that the image is disabling the debugger.  /* Don't watchdog when a debugger is attached. */ `DBGMCU_APB1PeriphConfig(DBGMCU_IWDG_STOP, ENABLE);`  will vary depending on STM32 framework version.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77810541/gdb-connection-timeout-on-port-4242-for-stm32-discovery-board

Comment: @artlessnoise: your answer was helpful, but, gdb doesn't stop on breakpoint and can't list (see 2d edit). Any clue why?

Comment: It needs to use hardware breakpoints (if it is in flash as usually is the case).  Make sure the st-link is recognizing the right processor. `st-info --probe` and other commands may help.  Not quite as simple to cross-debug as on a Linux PC.