# GDB connection timeout on port 4242 for STM32 Discovery board

Tags: gcc, arm, gdb, stm32

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have an STM32F4 Discovery board which has an stf32f407vg MCU on it.
I am trying to learn about linker scripts and starting files.
I have written a small linker(ld file) and start up file in which I am only declaring the size of flash and ram and then declaring the end of the stack and in the starter file I am just making the code start at beginning of flash(0x08000000). Or at least that's what I am trying to do :). I am guessing they are not very correct since it's my first try at something like this but since I am not entirely sure how relevant to the issue they are I will post them below:

The starter file:

```
    // These instructions define attributes of our chip and
// the assembly language we'll use:

    .syntax unified
    .cpu cortex-m4
    .thumb

// Import these symbols

    .extern   __ram_start__
    .extern   __ram_size__
    .extern   __ram_end__ 
    .extern   __stack_end__ 

// Global memory locations.
.global vtable
.global reset_handler


/*
 * The actual vector table.
 * Only the size of RAM and 'reset' handler are
 * included, for simplicity.
 */
 
 // Exception vector table--Common to all Cortex-M4

vtable:
    .word   __stack_end__
    .word   reset_handler
 
/*
 * The Reset handler. Called on reset.
*/

// Reset vector: In a real project this would do some RAM initialisations and then call main
    .thumb_func
reset_handler:
  // Set the stack pointer to the end of the stack.
  // The '__stack_end__' value is defined in our linker script.
  LDR  r0, =__stack_end__
  MOV  sp, r0

  // Set some dummy values. When we see these values
  // in our debugger, we'll know that our program
  // is loaded on the chip and working.
    LDR  r7, =0xDEADBEEF
    MOVS r0, #0
    main_loop:
    // Add 1 to register 'r0'.
    ADDS r0, r0, #1
    // Loop back.
    B    main_loop
```

And the linker file:

```
    /* Define the end of RAM and limit of stack memory */
/* (4KB SRAM on the STM32F031x6 line, 4096 = 0x1000) */
/* (RAM starts at address 0x20000000) */
/* _estack = 0x20001000;              */
/* In our code _estack = __stack_end__ */

MEMORY
{
    FLASH ( rx )      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
    RAM ( rxw )       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}


__ram_start__   = ORIGIN(RAM);
__ram_size__    = LENGTH(RAM);
__ram_end__     = __ram_start__ + __ram_size__;
__stack_end__   = __ram_end__;      /* Top of RAM */
```

I have then compiled and created an elf file and then converted it to a binary file which I have flashed on the board with STM32 Programmer. After flashing I tried to connect to the board with GDB and when I am getting connection timeout on port 4242 which as I understand should be the default port of STM devices - although on this I am not sure:

Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from main.elf...
(No debugging symbols found in main.elf)
(gdb) target extended-remote :4242
:4242: Connection timed out.

Please help me fix this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769639/how-to-remote-debug-stm32-code-with-gdb-using-stlink-tools-on-linux#comment137169310_77769639

Comment: the stack pointer is loaded for you from the vector table, you do not need to do it manually in your code

Comment: do you have openocd or other already connected and gdb is not connecting to that or do you not have openocd connected to the board?  (or are you using another tool than openocd?)

Comment: is gdb part of an ide/sdk you are using?  whose?

Answer (score 1):

GDB connects to remote target via a gdb-server. So you have to start a server on another terminal to be able to connect to the board.
You can do that by installing [**openocd**](https://openocd.org/pages/documentation.html) using your package manager.
After installing it you can start a server via openocd and pass it the config files for the interface (in this case, stlink) and target MCU (int this case, stm32f4x), like this:

```
openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f4x.cfg -c "init"
```

The argument after each `-f` flag are the paths to the interface and target MCU config files respectively, which will be installed with openocd on your system. If there's no errors, Running the above command will result in this messages:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J28S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.229005
Info : [stm32f4x.cpu] Cortex-M4 r0p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32f4x.cpu] target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32f4x.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

Severs are started and port 3333 will accept gdb connections.

Although the "vanilla" gdb won't work in this case and you either have to recompile it from source with configuration for your arm MCU, or use one of the binary packages that is compatible with arm MCUs, like `arm-none-eabi-gdb` or `gdb-multiarch` (package names may be different in ubuntu repositories).

Now you can run gdb in another terminal to connect with the board.

```
gdb-multiarch <path/to/main.elf>
```

or

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb <path/to/main.elf>
```

and in gdb prompt you can type (while openocd terminal is still running):

```
target extended-remote localhost:3333
```

and connect to the board. If you compile your code with debug info (using `-ggdb` flag) the debug symbols will load automatically to gdb.

Comment: you can telnet to 4444, which is much easier than gdb, stop read registers resume, etc...

Comment: I'm not sure about it being easier than gdb. gdb is sort of a "standard" debug tool and there's much more documentation for it. Also tui mode and scrolling through source and assembly code interactively can help a lot sometimes.

Comment: oscilloscope and uart and leds are primary debug tools for mcus.

Comment: I should have put my debugger comment under the question not this answer.  The notion of source code, and machine code, mixed together is also part of the problem.  And that implies you are building for debug, where you then should build for release and then debug everything twice.  Ive been at this for decades and other than customer support myself nor co-workers have had a use for a debugger like gdb.

Comment: Yes they help a lot of people, not needed for what the user is trying to do, but it is a tool and as with any tool you need to know the tool.  a lot of false sense of security with a tool like a debugger..

Answer (score 0):

No reason for this as you put the value on the vector table.

```
LDR  r0, =__stack_end__
MOV  sp, r0
```

Can leave it if you want but it adds nothing in this case.

Other than that you can tell from inspection that the result looks good. And it should execute fine.  (should always inspect before loading into the mcu)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <vtable>:
 8000000:   20020000    .word   0x20020000
 8000004:   08000009    .word   0x08000009

08000008 <reset_handler>:
 8000008:   4f01        ldr r7, [pc, #4]    ; (8000010 <main_loop+0x4>)
 800000a:   2000        movs    r0, #0

0800000c <main_loop>:
 800000c:   3001        adds    r0, #1
 800000e:   e7fd        b.n 800000c <main_loop>
 8000010:   deadbeef    .word   0xdeadbeef
```

As answered though you use openocd, no need for gdb (debuggers cause as many problems as they solve), just telnet in (port 4444 in the answer shown) and you can type help but it should be halt, reg, resume or halt, regs, resume and if you do it a few times you should see r0 change.

First thing you inspect is does the disassembly show the right address, in this case for most of the stm32s that is 0x08000000.
Is the vector table the first thing at that address? Is the first item the correct stack pointer initial value (if you are using the vector table to init the stack pointer, some folks cut and paste legacy code or from other platforms and do not care if this value is correct). Is the second item the correct address ORRED with 1 to the reset handler.

Then into this specific case, is the 0xDEADBEEF aligned?  It is but maybe dumb luck, likely want to sprinkle .aligns around in your code as dumb luck is 50/50 for this platform add or remove some code and things break.

You are using the f4 is a cortex-m4 so armv7m so all of the thumb instructions.  If this was a build for a cortex-m0 then you look for thumb2 instructions and most of them will fault the cortex-m0 (percentage-wise).  I generally build my bootstrap for m0/armv6m all the time to avoid bootstrap issues at least get it maybe into something I can halt and reprogram.

Inspecting the program itself and that looks good too.

Now you did not provide your disassembly so it may not match.  The first time you start a new build for an mcu project, arm based, or otherwise, do these dumps and see that you have a fighting chance to even boot.  Many boards you can brick the first program you put on the mcu.  Worth the few minutes.  After the Nth time of dealing with (rwx) issues in linker scripts I stopped using them all together.  I did find this solution educational as I have not seen it done this way (to generate  start and end variables).  gnus linker script is a nightmare to start with and what seems simple for start and end type variables is not, is something you also must validate before downloading the program otherwise more bricked boards to have to replace or unbrick.

As far as the gdb question, gdb needs something to connect to, sure it could be active on the firmware image, but you would have a ton of code in your binary for that.  So gdb needs to connect to something in the middle.  Openocd is the tool of choice for this for arm based platforms, particularly ones like discovery and Nucleo boards from st.  Or real or fake jlink boards connected to other cortex-m based products (and full sized ARMs too).  And then if desired you can connect gdb to openocd then openocd handles the gdb commands.

What is not understood here is do you have openocd or some equivalent connected to the discovery board and gdb cannot connect to openocd?  Of did you not connect openocd to the chip (make the connection as shown in another answer).

Success from openocd generally ends with some number of breakpoints and some number of watchpoints and openocd remains resident and does not exit.  If you do not get to that point and or you do but it kicks out or starts printing that it disconnected, etc.  You have to solve the openocd issue before solving the gdb issue.

Note that resetting the board, with the button, will upset openocd, sometimes you can just reconnect, but note that that does not always work and you may instead wish to kill openocd (Ctrl-C in that window) and restart it.

If this is an authentic discovery board from ST (or also for Nucleo boards) I highly recommend finding the firmware update tool (Java, works on Linux, Windows, Mac and talks to st to find firmware you don't have to keep updating it the tool) and update the firmware on the debug mcu on the board, then unplug and replug the board.  As the operating systems evolve relative to the firmware on that mcu you can get connection issues, reliability issues on Nucleo boards after a relatively small number of times copying the binary over to the board it stops working, etc...

If this is more likely a fake/clone discovery board, then, well they are flakey at best, buy them by the handfuls and toss the ones that are not reliable, and I would not mess with their firmware.

With a discovery you need to get the firmware on the mcu in the first place (with a nucleo, I highly recommend nucleo boards over discovery, you simply copy/drag and drop the binary).  IMO just telnet in

```
telnet localhost 4444
```

then it will have a message that it is connected to openocd.

```
reset halt
flash write_image erase mybinary.elf
reset
```

with a path to your binary file, it supports the elf file format and then you do not have to specify an address. (I name mine .elf, but it may be different for you). (One can simply type help on the command line to see all the commands)

You can also look at the registers without the excess work of trying to get gdb working.  But these things can be done with gdb as well.